# nodejs server deployed in Azure is outputting content length

Tags: node.js, azure, iis

My `server.js` looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    const configs = {
        apiBaseUrl: 'http://myUrl'
    };

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };
    response.writeHead(200, headers);
    response.end(JSON.stringify(configs));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

when i run this locally it outputs what it should:

```
{"apiBaseUrl":"http://myUrl"}
```

But when deployed to my Azure instance it behaves slightly different. It also outputs the number of chars:

```
29
{"apiBaseUrl":"http://myUrl"}
0
```

Any clue what could cause this issue?

**Edit:**
i forgot to mention that i am deploying to Azure and have a `web.config` in place:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Get dynamic configs in server environment" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="configs.json" ignoreCase="true"/>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="currentConfigs.js" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="currentConfigs.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I spun up an app service using the "Node JS Empty Web App" from the marketplace, copied and pasted your code, and received the expected, JSON only output, so I'm not sure why this is happening for you. How are you running your code in Azure?

Comment: hi @MitchStewart i have a web.config in place that uses the iisnode handler. forgot to mention that. thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the following observation:

In Azure Portal i **turned on Application Insights site extension** by clicking the button.

[image]

This automatically created the following settings:

- APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
- APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION: 1.0.0
- APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION: 1.0.0
- ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~2
- DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~3
- InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~1
- SnapshotDebugger_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~1
- XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions: ~1
- XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode: recommended

The response of my node request is now:

```
29
{"apiBaseUrl":"http://myUrl"}
0
```

After playing around with those new values i found the value causing the issue:

- ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION: **~2**

Changing this to ~1 solved the issue and the response looked as desired:

- ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION: **~1**

response:

```
{"apiBaseUrl":"http://myUrl"}
```

I think this is a super strange behavior. I will create a github issue and link it.

Comment: This does seem strange. Did you ever create a Github issue?

Comment: Not yet. Will do it in the next days.